# Canny filter and distance measurment between pixels

Tags: image-processing, octave

I want to measure some distances between the edges detected by some filter method such as 'Canny'. I am using 'Octave'. I tried this simple command to get the edges of the following image.

```
a = imread('img1.jpg');
b = rgb2gray(a);
BW = edge(b, 'Canny');
imshow(BW);
```

[image]

After that I have no idea how to apply least square data fitting method to fit every edge to a circle.

Comment: That looks like an scientific image to me. Are you looking for distances in pixels or any other unit?

Comment: Forget the idea of measuring the thickness of the upper edge of the "bowl". Low contrast, blur and adverse illumination make it impossible. The lower outline of the bowl is also so fuzzy...

Comment: That is the image of an eye. To curve is the cornea and the marked region with red marker is lens of an eye. The edges can be detected easily with Canny filter. The unit at the moment does not matter. So distance in pixels would work for me.

Comment: From both the [tag:octave] and [tag:matlab] tag descriptions: "Don’t use both the [matlab] and [octave] tags, unless the question is explicitly about the similarities or differences between the two."

Comment: I think, once you detect the edges (you said you can do that), you create a binary image with the edges only and then just count the "black pixels" (non edge) in a straight line, within the desired area... wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: @beaker I wouldn't want that 'rule' to be applied so stringently tbh. My main gripe with double-tagging is when people post double-tagged questions that don't in fact actually apply to both languages (and hence one of the tags is invalid) ... but that's about it.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I agree, mindlessly applying any rule is generally a bad thing. In this case I had very specific reasons to suggest following the rule.